# WildCard Query in hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search, querydsl

We are using Hibernate search to search the lucene index annoted in my entity.
I have to return a list of string which  contains a keyString, basically a substring operation.
This is my code

```
public List<Member> lookForMembers(String searchText) {

    QMember qmember = QMember.member1;

    FullTextSession session = Search.getFullTextSession((Session) tenwdb.getDelegate());

    SearchQuery<Member> query = new SearchQuery<Member>(session, qmember);

    return query.where(qmember.name.contains(searchText).or(qmember.profile.profileDisplayUri.contains(searchText))).list();

}
```

Does this operation gets all the strings and does a substring operation or does it invoke a WildcardQuery on lucene.

Appreciate if some one an help me using the WildCardQuery for hibernate search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.3/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html

This URL has all the details required. Thanks for all who looked into it